# Unsupported languages Text To Speech engine for android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Hi I am building an android application that uses tts engine. I need the app to speak unsupported languages, be it Hindi(Language in India). Is it possible?

After googling a couple of hours i came across this 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tts-for-android/_1-JG149quw

But where can i find android tts engine that supports hindi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eSpeak TTS engine (available on the Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.googlecode.eyesfree.espeak)) has support for Hindi, but the quality is not very good.